# How to create independent Paid Apple Watch App?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, apple-watch.app

I have an iOS App in the App Store using iCloud and it is for **free**

Now I would like to create independent Apple Watch App with similar functionality as an iOS App using the same iCloud container and its data. Apple Watch app is to be a **paid** app.

How can I accomplish that?

1. Should I create another app in appstoreconnect.apple.com or can I use the same app as it is for iOS app already?
2. Should I create separated xcode project and which option should I select then...

[image]

or...

3. should I create another target and what option should I select then?

[image]